# Significance of giving Rs. 51 or 101 as donation

Tags: belief, rituals, practice, tradition

What is the significance of giving cash as donation, gifts or dakshina in numbers such as 51, 101, and 501?

Comment: I think the appropriate word would be Charity (righteous charity) , for punya  the charity should be given to a rightful patra like a bramhana (who performs his duty very well).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the significance of odd numbers in Hinduism?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10870/1049)

Comment: @iammilind I think this question is about specific numbers 51,101. Marked question is for odd numbers.

Comment: @AnilKumar, I feel that other Q covers this part as well. Hence I have edited, so that above numbers are also covered. If that post receives a complete answer then for sure, this Q will also get the answer. This post discusses just 1 aspect of the other post, hence I suggested to be duplicate. BTW, if a linked Q is without an upvoted or accepted answer (like other post), then it's moderator's discretion to close. We can just flag it at the max.

Comment: From what Ive heard, 1 rupee(or whatever currency) is for pujari and rest is for temple. Hence here in my place and possibly other places to when on 12th day we visit temple after some1 passes away, we give exact round figure as charity; 100,500 and not 101 or 501 ;since no service of pujari is required that time. So probably this idea got later adapted in other fields of charity as well other than temple.